# Is it possible to convert Logitech Unifying-ready mouse into bluetooth mouse?

Tags: logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech m330 silent and I really don't like the dongle, it is USB-A and I only have USB-C ports.

Is it possible to get completely rid of the usb dongle?

Comment: You can just get a passive adapter.  They are cheap.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to get rid of usb dongle completely?

Not in any way practical or economical.  The electronics inside a USB mouse are very different from the electronics inside a Bluetooth mouse.

Your best way forward is to get a Blue Tooth mouse. I use LogiTech Blue Tooth Mice and they work just fine.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't do that?

Comment: Because the electronics are different inside the mice between USB and Bluetooth.  I added that point to my answer

Comment: They're incompatible technologies; one proprietary, the other open source - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Unifying_receiver

Answer (score 1):

It seems your real problem is you don't have any usb type A port.

1. Get a USB hub that plugs into your PC with a type C, but the hub will definitely offer USB type A ports.
2. Get a docking station, these have type C plug

Comment: I have a frankenstein dongle with typeA to typeC adapter in it. but it so long and bulky - I want to get rid of this. Logitech does not provide any type c options for dongles

Answer (score 0):

There are a few niche solutions like Kuwee X1 (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3256804318350151.html) that works as USB host and Bluetooth HID guest at the same time, forwarding any USB HID input from wired, Unifying or other common dongles to Bluetooth recipients.

The same can be achieved with a Linux PC, typically an SBC like Raspberry Pi that is always on: https://github.com/HeuristicPerson/bluetooth_2_hid

Comment: Link only answers are not very good.  You could improve your answer by adding some features of the two gadgets.